# How to add additional collection data to document with Cloud Firestore?

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, google-cloud-firestore, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines

Data is read from cloud firestore (red) which is static data and stored locally in a room database

[image: cloud firestore]

```
private val _fetchedJourneys = MutableLiveData<List<Journey>>()
override val fetchedJourneys: LiveData<List<Journey>>
   get() = _fetchedJourneys

    override suspend fun getJourneys() {
        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                .collection(COLLECTION_JOURNEY)
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {

                        val fetchedJourneys = arrayListOf<Journey>()

                        for (queryDocumentSnapshot in task.result!!) {
                            val journey = queryDocumentSnapshot.toObject(Journey::class.java)
                            journey.id = queryDocumentSnapshot.id

                           // At this point I have the journey ID, which in return I  
                           // need to query the progress collection to look for the timestamp and add 
                           // its value it to journey.lastOpened

                            fetchedJourneys.add(journey)
                        }

                        _fetchedJourneys.postValue(fetchedJourneys)

                        Timber.d("Fetched ${fetchedJourneys.size} journeys remotely")

                    } else {
                        Timber.e(task.exception!!.message, "Failed to fetch remote journeys")
                    }
                }

    }
```

Object:

```
@Entity(tableName = "journeys")
@IgnoreExtraProperties
@Parcelize
data class Journey(
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
        @SerializedName("journey_id")
        var id: String = "",
        val title: String = "",
        val description: String = "",
        val image: String = "",
        @ColumnInfo(name = "last_opened")
        var lastOpened: String = ""
) : Parcelable
```

There is also some 'progress' data that is dynamic and is different per user. The field that is located in the **progress** collection is a timestamp that has to be added to the `lastOpened` property of the `Journey` object and is in a document with the userId as the documentId.

I'm a beginner with the firebase API and I know that all calls are asynchronous, but I can't seem to think about a way to add property 'progress' (yellow) to the object (red) on a call to the object.

Can I achieve this in the app or do I need to rearrange the way I save the data?

Comment: To understand better, please rephrase the question. Progress is not a property

Answer (score 0):

What you're outlining in yellow would not be a "property".  That would be a subcollection.  You can nest more documents under it, just like you are already with "chapters".

There is no API to create a subcollection.  Just start writing documents to it normally, and it will be created if needed.

If you are asking about writing additional fields to a document, like you have already with description and image, then you simply call `update()` on a reference to that document.

Comment: I mean a property of an object. I retreive the object and then later retrieve the progress with it's Id. This then gets added to the object.

Comment: Firestore doesn't have properties and objects.  It has collections, documents, and fields.  Everything you model in Firestore should revolve around these concepts.

Comment: But locally it's an object I use, in the kotlin android app. I read it from firebase to store it on the device (Android Room).

Comment: Maybe you would like to edit the question to show the code you have that isn't working the way you expect, and add more detail about what you're trying to accomplish with that code.  At the end of the day, you're going to have to work with collections, documents, and fields in order to things to make sense in the database.

Comment: I added more information. Hopefully this can help :)

Comment: To understand better, please rephrase the question. Progress is not a property.

Comment: @MrTech Did you mean to comment on the question, and not on my answer?

Comment: @DougStevenson: The message was for Rafael

Comment: @MrTech Then you should probably comment on the question, not on my answer.

Comment: What I've done now is loop through the journeys and for each journey, get the lastOpened field in the progress collection and add it to the journey.